# SQL Server query slow with small timespan, quick with large timespan

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I'm struggling with a specific query.

It runs very slow (15 seconds / 33 rows) when I only filter for the last 7 days.

It runs very fast (0 seconds / 7071 rows) when I filter from 2010 until now.

Here are the queries, the only difference is the timestamp filter :

```
Select l.linkid as [Data]
from tblsearchresult sr with (nolock) 
inner join tbllink l with (nolock) on l.linkid = sr.linkid
where 
    sr.searchtaskid in (817) and
    l.timestamp between '2015-08-04 00:00:00:000' and '2015-08-10 23:59:59:999'

Select l.linkid as [Data]
from tblsearchresult sr with (nolock) 
inner join tbllink l with (nolock) on l.linkid = sr.linkid
where 
    sr.searchtaskid in (817) and
    l.timestamp between '2010-01-01 00:00:00:000' and '2015-08-10 23:59:59:999'
```

My question is, what are the possible causes of the slowdown?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reindexing the table ? Maybe the indexes for the newer values are missing ?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Probably the ascending date problem and you need to update statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the execution plans.  If they are the same, then the problem would be warm cache versus cold cache.  The first time you run the query, the data needs to be loaded.  Queries run much faster when the data is already in memory.

More likely, it is just an inefficient optimization.  The first query might use an index on `tbllink(timestamp)`, but the second doesn't.

For these queries, I would recommend writing the query:

```
Select sr.linkid as [Data]
from tblsearchresult sr with (nolock) inner join
     tbllink l with (nolock)
     on l.linkid = sr.linkid
where sr.searchtaskid in (817) and
      (l.timestamp >= '2010-01-01' and
       l.timestamp < '2015-08-11'
      );
```

(This just changes the source for the `select` and uses cleaner date arithmetic.)

Try a query on `tblsearchresult(searchtaskid, linkid)` and `tbllink(linkid, timestamp)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I analysed the execution plan and saw the slow query used a different index on tblSearchResult and als used "Hash Join" on tblLink. 

I changed the "inner join" on tbllink to an "inner loop join" and the query ran very quick (2 seconds)...It also uses the other index now, I don't know, do you have an explanation?